# MySQL SET PASSWORD executing fine with 0 rows affected but not taking effect?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# app where if you click a button it will take whatever the password text box has and attempt to set the MySQL database with that user in usernameLabel.Text. However, this executes fine but I can still refresh the database in PHPMyAdmin and it works fine with the old password. The new password gives an access denied so it clearly hasn't changed the password even though there were no errors. Does anyone have an idea on why this might be the case?

This is the code for the button.

```
private void submitNewMySQLPasswordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["system"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(connection);

    myconn.Open();

    MySqlCommand command = myconn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('@NewPassHere') WHERE User='@User';";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", usernameLabel.Text);
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?hostname", "%");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPassHere", newPasswordTextBox.Text);
    int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    myconn.Close();
}
```

Comment: If ExecuteNonQuery returns 0 then your "command" is not "executing fine".

Comment: Hey Steve - thanks, what value should ExecuteNonQuery be returning? It returns 1 now after Progman's comment, but just curious what this return value reflects.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by your command. If it returns 0 then it has not found anything to update. If it returns 1 then the command has updated/inserted/deleted 1 row. In any case you should go for the official documentation on MSDN site to know every detail of this and other ADO.NET methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around the parameters, otherwise it's just an ordinary string.

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(@NewPassHere) WHERE User=@User;";
command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=usernameLabel.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@NewPassHere", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=newPasswordTextBox.Text);
int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Not sure if is fine flagging for close (because of typo) or not

Comment: @Progman that made ExecuteNonQuery return 1 however I can still login with the old password and not the new. As a side note, the MySQL engine version is 5.6.5.

Comment: @Progman, I can see in the mysql.user table, the password does infact change as I can see the hash changing, yet I can still login with the old one. Do you reckon I need to do a flush privileges right after the UPDATE?

Comment: @sushi7777 Yes, as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privilege-changes.html since you don't use the account-management statements.

Comment: Thank you so much :) adding a "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" fixed it :)